# Fill a string array by repeating each element according to the values of another int array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string array [x,y,z] and an int array [2,3,4] and I need to create an array by appending the two, but having the last 3 values multiplied by the integers in the int array, like so:
[x,y,z,xx,yyy,zzzz]. I can't figure out how to do this.
What I wrote is this:

```
public static String[] bigArr (String[] letters, int[] numbers) {
        int l = letters.length;
        int n = numbers.length;
        String[] answer = new String[l+n];
        for (int i=0; i<n;i++){
                answer[i]=letters[i]+numbers[i];

        }
        return answer;      
    }
```

Obviously it returns nonsense at this point, but I am stuck and need a good explanation on how to do this. I am very new to Java.

Comment: do you want to concat letters with numbers array's element? also both array have same size?

Comment: @javaseeker - I need to concatenate the first array [x,y,z] with another array created by multiplying the letters by the numbers values: if I have an array like [2,3,4] this means that the x will be repeated 2 times, y - 3 times and z - 4 times. The final result would be [x,y,z (the original string array), xx,yyy,zzzz(letters multiplied by values of int array)]. Both arrays are same size, yes.

Comment: @GabrielNegut , no he doesn't  want all the possible compilations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] letters = {"x", "y", "z"};
    int[] numbers = {2, 3, 4};

    String[] result = bigArr(letters, numbers);

    // prints [x, y, z, xx, yyy, zzzz]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}

private static String[] bigArr(String[] letters, int[] numbers) {
    int lettersLength = letters.length;
    int numbersLength = numbers.length;

    String[] result = new String[lettersLength + numbersLength];

    for (int n = 0; n < lettersLength; ++n) {
        result[n] = letters[n];
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int n = lettersLength; n < result.length; ++n) {
        sb.setLength(0); // reset the StringBuilder

        for (int m = 0; m < numbers[n - lettersLength]; ++m) {
            sb.append(letters[n - lettersLength]);
        }

        result[n] = sb.toString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 . First, copy the letters to `answer`

2 . Then, for each letter `l[i]`,

`answer[l + i - 1] = string_consisting_of_letter_l[i]_repeated_n[i]_times`